# Converting normals to global coordinate system

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, normals

**Update:
Yea, I solved it. Someone told me to use gluLookAt() with ModelView matrix active. Now I use it with Projection matrix and matrix calculations works as they should.**

Im am writing simple lighing shader on GLSL.

Code: http://pastebin.com/vdzyGVBS

```
/// VERTEX
//uniform mat4 gl_ProjectionMatrixTranspose;
//uniform mat4 gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrixTranspose;

//uniform mat4 gl_ModelViewMatrixTranspose;
uniform mat4 gl_ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 gl_ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 gl_NormalMatrix;

varying vec3 norm;
varying vec4 color;


void main()
{
    //norm = normalize(gl_Normal) * mat3(gl_ModelViewMatrix); // It should work, but result is very weird

    //norm = normalize(gl_Normal) * transpose(mat3(gl_ModelViewMatrix)); // I don't know why, but it transforms normals to camera/eye coordinates

    norm = normalize(gl_Normal); // Light level is constant, event when model is rotating

    color = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

and

```
/// FRAGMENT 
const float dirlight_factor = 1.0;
const float amblight_factor = 0.2;
const float ambshad_factor = 0.1;

varying vec3 norm;
varying vec4 color;

void main()
{
    float shade;
    float nz = normalize(norm).z;
    if (nz > 0)
    {
        shade = amblight_factor + (nz * (dirlight_factor-amblight_factor));
    }
    else
    {
        shade = ambshad_factor + ((nz + 1) * (amblight_factor-ambshad_factor));
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * shade, color.a);
}
```

All works fine, but when I trying to rotate model with ModelView matrix polygons do not change their light level. Seems that normals are not affected by ModelView matrix transformation. I tried many matrix transforamtions, but none of them worked. <s>So, how I can trasform normals to global coordinate system?</s> **So, how I can transform both light direction and normals into same coordinate system (world space or eye/camera space)?**

**Update:**

> Is the intent to have a world-space directional light or a directional "headlight" coming from your camera?

.

> I just realized (I just focused on the normal transformation part), that you do not pass light parameters of any kind to the shaders. No wonder you don't see proper illumination.

I don't pass any light parametrs because I don't need to change them.
I trying to do world-space directional light that always falls from +Z to -Z.

Comment: Is the intent to have a world-space directional light or a directional "headlight" coming from your camera?

Answer (score 0):

It transforms normals to eye coordinates because you're multiplying them by the modelview matrix. The model matrix transforms coordinates to world space, then the view matrix transforms coordinates to eye space. You'll have to pass the two matrices in separately if you want to transform the normals to world space, then you'll have to multiply them in the shader.

Answer (score 0):

Tangent spaces (normals are part of the basis of local tangent space) don't transform by the regular modelview matrix. Instead they must be transformed by the *transposed inverse* of the modelview matrix.

In your code you wrote

```
// It should work, but result is very weird
//norm = normalize(gl_Normal) * mat3(gl_ModelViewMatrix);
```

Nope, it should, and will not work, because normals do not transform to the same rules as positions. Also order of operations matter and reversing the order of multiplication will just transpose the results, but it misses that inverse part; however a hunch tells me, that you did't write the normal vector on the left side of the multiplication on purpose to transpose the whole thing.

As already said normals are part of a local space coordinate system base. You already have that uniform `gl_NormalMatrix` in there, and it most likely contains this.

So your code should look like

```
norm = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
```

#### Update

I just realized (I just focused on the normal transformation part), that you do not pass light parameters of any kind to the shaders. No wonder you don't see proper illumination.

Comment: I testing it on a sphere that rotates around Y axis. If normals are transported right, light shold fall in -Z direction.       If I use `norm = normalize(gl_Normal) * mat3(gl_ModelViewMatrix);` lightsourse flies in a strange '8'-like trajectory around that sphere.       If I use `norm = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);` light is falling in direction of sight and swings a little.

Comment: @user2752075: That "swinging" effect could be caused if you do illumination computations on a per vertex base instead of a per fragment base. Light directions being off is an indicator that you transformed the light positions wrong. In general you should do all illumination calculations in view space. But for that you must make sure that you apply the right transformation. Which made me realize, that you don't pass light positions into your shaders at all.

Comment: @user2752075: If you're using just the projection of the normal toward the Z axis, which is essentially what your shader does, that "light" would fall in from the +Z direction.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly how I want this shader to work.
Ok, now now I'll try to do the calculations inside eye/camera space. Transforming normal using this:
`vec3 norm = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);`
(that "swinging" is a normal calculation bug in gluSphere() that occurs if I try to draw low-polygonal spheres).
But I still can't figure out how to transform light direction (vec3(0, 0, -1.0)) from world space to eye/camera space.

Comment: @user2752075: The swinging is not a bug, it's an artifact of per-vertex illumination calculation. Yes it is pronounced for low triangle counts. But it can be completely avoided by doing the illumination calculation in the fragment shader on a per-fragment base (also called pixel based illumination), which is the standard approach on the problem for, well, ever since shaders had been available.

Comment: @user2752075: When it comes to light calculations. Well, you have to transform the world space _direction_ (hence part of a coordinate system base) into view space, and since it's a direction the same rules as for normals apply, i.e. a directional light gets transformed by the transpose inverse of the matrix that transforms directions of the space the light is defined in into eye space. In your case that would be world to view transformation. *Take note that this is usually a different transformation than the modelview matrix does.* Namely it's just the *view* part of the model view.

Comment: @user2752075: And this is the very moment where you should stop using the OpenGL built-in matrix manipulation functions and use a real matrix math library (like GLM, Eigen, linmath.h); everything else is pure masochism. So what you do is building an assortment of matrices (projection, view, per model modelview transform and so on) and compound them as you need them. Or in the case of getting a directional light to work, you'd transform the directional vector you're interested in with the transpose inverse of the view transform and pass that as an additional uniform.